# How to send sensitive data to an Asp.net Web API server

Tags: asp.net, http, asp.net-web-api, security

I have a Asp.net Web API project.

The project validates all the requests by receiving a parameter named `sessionToken`

`http://myapi.com/api/applications/getApplications?sessionToken=xxx`

However, i heard that is not safe to send the sensitive parameters via public urls, and i've seen an [example](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) where i can add the `sessionToken` parameter inside the header of the `HttpClient` request:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://myapi.com/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("sessionToken", "xxx");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/applications/getApplications");
    string stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I am happy that now i can read the parameter without having to put it in the url.

Is it safe to send sensitive data via http request headers? (of course that they will be encrypted at least)

Answer (score 2):

You are right that putting security sensitive information on Url is not a good idea. It can lead to information disclosure.

Putting it to header is recommended. Here are some further suggestions:

- Use [Authorize](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p7-auth-22) header instead of custom header. Authorize header is designed for authentication purpose. You can define your own scheme or you can use existing scheme like [bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) defined in OAuth 2.0 instead of reinventing all wheels.
- Client should always use TLS to protect from [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attack
- Client should always check certificate chain when making request to avoid [DNS hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_hijacking) attack
- Set expiration on token to be short lived to avoid [replay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) attack
- Make sure your client code won't store token to unsafe places, which can be access by others

Comment: Thank you..i will research on each of them to see how can i defend properly...Dangers everywhere!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the connection is encrypted, I believe sending any sensitive information in url or header is not a good idea. If you want to still send it over unsecured http, use some short of public/private key encryption which can encrypted the data. I have build an application where the url contain some encrypted data which is valid for a short span (for example 2 mins).